# Why returning List of HashMap instead of a HashMap? Scala

Tags: list, scala, hashmap

I have this function that from two lists, I want it  to construct a HashMap:

```
def storeHashmap(
    keys: List[List[Option[String]]],
    similarities: List[Float]
  ): List[HashMap[Float, (String, String)]] = {
    for ((k, s) <- (keys.zip(similarities)))
      yield HashMap(s -> (k.head.get, k(k.length - 1).get))
  }
```

Instead of returning `HashMap[Float, (String, String)]`, it returns `List[HashMap[Float, (String, String)]`
What am I missing? I don't want to use reduce at the end! I want to concatenate the hashMap according to iterations for its construction

Comment: You yielding the value and it is returning Collection of Hash Map, you iterating over list and creating map so it will be List of Map

Comment: Okay what should I change thhen in order to yield hashmap instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def storeHashmap(
                    keys: List[List[Option[String]]],
                    similarities: List[Float]
                  ): Map[Float, (String, String)] = {
    val yieldOutput = for ((k, s) <- keys.zip(similarities))
      yield s -> (k.head.get, k.last.get)
    yieldOutput.toMap
  }
```